# Creating Bitmap Image or Memory stream from xaml control using Sharpdx library(WinRT)

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, sharpdx

Is it possible to create a Bitmap image or memory stream of xaml control say(gird, canvas) from Sharpdx. I need to create an image from one of my window for implementing Secondary tile Pin To start functionality.

Comment: I answered this (I hope!) with code samples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627830/creating-bitmap-image-from-xaml-control-using-writablebitmapex

Answer (score -3):

I've been using the RandomAccessStreamReference class in Windows.Storage.Streams to create bitmaps. One example (this is actually code for sharing):

```
        var reference = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri(item.ImagePath.AbsoluteUri));
        request.Data.SetBitmap(reference);
```

Also keep in mind that for pinning secondary tiles, you can pass in a URI for the logo on the tile, without creating an actual bitmap, as long as the logo is part of your app package, like this:

```
    var uri = new Uri(item.TileImagePath.AbsoluteUri);

    var tile = new SecondaryTile(
            item.UniqueId,              // Tile ID
            item.ShortTitle,            // Tile short name
            item.Title,                 // Tile display name
            item.UniqueId,              // Activation argument
            TileOptions.ShowNameOnLogo, // Tile options
            uri                         // Tile logo URI
        );

    await tile.RequestCreateAsync();
```

Finally, if your image that you want to use on the secondary tile is online rather than part of your app package, you will have to copy it locally before you can use it. Here is some code that does that:

```
    // This is the URI that you will then pass as the last parameter into 
    // the Secondary Tile constructor, like the code above:
    var logoUri = await GetLocalImageAsync(restaurant.ImagePath, restaurant.Key);

    // and here's the method that does the meat of the work:

/// <summary>
/// Copies an image from the internet (http protocol) locally to the AppData LocalFolder.
/// This is used by some methods (like the SecondaryTile constructor) that do not support 
/// referencing images over http but can reference them using the ms-appdata protocol.  
/// </summary>
/// <param name="internetUri">The path (URI) to the image on the internet</param>
/// <param name="uniqueName">A unique name for the local file</param>
/// <returns>Path to the image that has been copied locally</returns>
private async Task<Uri> GetLocalImageAsync(string internetUri, string uniqueName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(internetUri))
    {
        return null;
    }

    using (var response = await HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(internetUri).GetResponseAsync())
    {
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var desiredName = string.Format("{0}.jpg", uniqueName);
            var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(desiredName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            using (var filestream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(filestream);
                return new Uri(string.Format("ms-appdata:///local/{0}.jpg", uniqueName), UriKind.Absolute);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the answer what i am expected to get. Here you demonstrated the way to create PinToTile. What i am asked is something different. I don’t have an image to pin with my hand; My requirement is, I had a control with me with some data(say a grid or canvas) i need to create an image from that control and then i need to pin that image to start screen. Hope you understand my issue. I can use WritableBitmap.Render () method in wp7 and wpf to create image from a control. But in WINRT don’t. I need a solution to this issue.